# How to express summation in terms of vector?

Tags: vector-spaces, summation, vector-analysis

I am trying to understand the equation wherein the summation is expressed in terms of vector as shown below:

$z_q(n) = \left(A_{SR}h_q^{SR}+\alpha A_{TR}A_{SR}\sum_{m=1}^Mh_{q,m}^{TR}h_{m}^{ST}x_m\right)s(n)+w_q(n)$-----(1)

The (1) is divided by $A_{SR}$. Therefore , eq.(1) is written as

$\bar{z_q(n)} = \left(h_q^{SR}+\textbf{h}_q^{TR}\textbf{G}\textbf{x}\right)s(n)+\bar{w_q(n)}$----(2)

where $\bar{z_q(n)} = \frac{z_q(n)}{A_{SR}}$, $\bar{w_q(n)} = \frac{w_q(n)}{A_{SR}}$,

$\textbf{x} = [x_1,x_2,...,x_M]^T$, $\textbf{h}_q^{TR} = [h_{q,1}^{TR},h_{q,2}^{TR},...,h_{q,M}^{TR}]$ and $\textbf{G}=\alpha A_{TR}\text{diag}\left(h_1^{ST},h_2^{ST},...,h_M^{ST}\right)$-----(A)

I am no getting how the summation part of eq.(1) is expressed into vector $\textbf{x},\textbf{h}_q^{TR} $ and matrix $\textbf{G}$ of eq. (A).

Any help in this regard will be highly appreciated.

Comment: Any help in this regard will be highly appreciated......

Comment: Got this one.....Thank you.....